# ValidationSummary error messages not responding to style text-align:left

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Every first ValidationSummary error message appears to the right and others appears to the left. 
I tried to add class to it and I have set css text-align:left to the class but nothing change

here is screenshot to be more clear 
invalid Email Address appears first
[image]

**View**

```css
.validation-summary-valid {
        display: none;
    }
    .toLeft{
        text-align:left;
    }
    
/*To change the color of selected tab*/
    .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
        background-color: #E8E8E8;
    }
    /*To set submit button right*/
    li:last-child {
        float: right;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    td {
        position: relative;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    td {
        left: 10px;
    }

        td:first-child {
            left: 0px;
        }

        td:nth-child(3) {
            left: 20px;
        }

    a {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Add</h2>

<hr>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.ValidationSummary(string.Empty, new { @class = "alert alert-danger toLeft" })
<br>
    <div id="wizard">
    // other code...
```

Comment: Because you have a `li:last-child { float: right; }` (`ValidationSummary()` generates a `<ul>` with `<li>` elements (and you can delete your `.validation-summary-valid` and `.toLeft` styles)

Comment: it is right thanks @Stephen Muecke can you please write your comment as answer ?so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.ValidationSummary()` generates a `<ul>` with `<li>` elements for each error message.

Because you have included a `li:last-child { float: right; }` style, your last error message is being displayed to the right.

Since you appear to want that style applied to only your 'Save' button, then you should give that button (or its `<li>` container) an `id` attribute and then use that to style the button to float to the right.

You can also delete the `toLeft` class in the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` and the associated `.toLeft { text-align:left; }` style since its left-aligned by default.